# gulp dest в ту же директорию

Tags: gulp

Как сделать так чтобы галп добавлял файлы в те же директории

```
 gulp.task('templates', function() {
'use strict';
var includeDirs = ['app/pages/', 'app/blocks/**'];
return gulp.src(['app/pages/*.njk','app/blocks/**/*.njk'])
    .pipe(rename({extname: ".html"})) // допустим мы поменяли формат
    .pipe(gulp.dest() // теперь надо вставить файлы в те же директории
    ...
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас действительно так как вы написали, то, во-первых,вы забыли скобку закрыть после `gulp.dest()`. Во-вторых для получения пути используйте функцию с получением `.base` для возврата значения пути местоположения файла.

Должно выглядеть таким образом:

```
 gulp.task('templates', function() {
'use strict';
var includeDirs = ['app/pages/', 'app/blocks/**'];
return gulp.src(['app/pages/*.njk','app/blocks/**/*.njk'])
    .pipe(rename({extname: ".html"})) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
                      return file.base;
                   })
         ) 
    ...
    ...
});
```